# Visual Web Developer 2010 Intellisense Broken

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, visual-web-developer

**My Problem**

In Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010, my intellisense suddenly stopped working today for my front end HTML (.aspx) files but is still working fine for code behind (.cs) files.

Along with this, when I hover over any asp control declared in my aspx pages, it says

```
validation(): Element 'control' is not supported.
validation(): Element 'label' is not supported.
etc...
```

(side note: 'control' and 'label' are lowercase in the message, instead of the proper case)

**My Progress**

I have been looking around for answers,

- a few people suggested deleting certain files, such as  the "*.ncb", 
  but I have not been able to find any MS files with this extention
  anywhere (hidden files are visible).
- I have a "Web Site", not a "Project" so within my site there are no
  *.sln", *.proj, *.suo" files to delete either.
- One suggestion was to "Clean" my project, but I can't find that
  option anywhere.
- Another person suggestion running "MS Developer command prompt" and
  executing a utility called "devenv" with certain arguments. I do not
  have the "MS Developer command prompt", I assume because I am using
  the Express Edition. I cannot find the devenv utility in my file
  system as well.
- I have checked all my master pages but haven't noticed anything
  weird.
- I looked in the Tools > Options menu but didn't find any "intellisense" type of thing anywhere. My "Show all settings" is turned on.
- I tried changing the doc type in the dropdown from XHTML 1.0 Transitional to all the other things just to see, with no luck.

**My Plea to fellow .Net-ers**

My website builds just fine with no errors, it's just having no intellisense on my aspx pages is driving me nuts.

Is there anything else I can try? Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

DevEnv is the program name for visual studio - it will be here:

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"** on a 64 bit OS
or 
**"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"** on a 32 bit OS.
Right click on the icon you use to run VS and then click properties and it will tell you where this file is in the Target box.

To clean a project, right click the project in the solution explorer and then click Clean.

Visual studio command prompt will be in the start menu under:
**Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 > Visual Studio Tools**
There may be several version depending if you are running on a 64bit OS, Itanium, etc. You can also just run DevEnv from the Run box or ordinary command prompt. 
The 32bit version can be run from the Run Box using the following (if on 64 bit, add **" (x86"** after "Program Files"):

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

Personally, after closing down VS and rebooting the machine to check if it was just a process crash causing it (i.e. restart from a fresh OS and VS load) - I would reset option (see here [/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

Good luck, and please reply back mif this worked or did not so to give the thread a conclusion. :D

Comment: I can't find devenv.exe anywhere on my computer. I assume it is because I am using Visual Web Developer Express. Thanks though.

Comment: I think in VS2010 Web Developer Express the executable is vwdexpress.exe (have a look at the properties of the icon you launch it from).

Comment: Not sure if it applies [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853016/intellisense-stops-working-in-vwd-2010) (and no answers to it yet) but if you run the trial and then stepped down to express after the trial, it seems that this breaks intellisense for projects created before the step down

Comment: From an elevated cmd I ran "C:\...\VWDExpress.exe /ResetSettings". It looked like it did something, but intellisense is still broken.

Comment: I tried repairing the install and still messed up. I will go ahead and accept your answer since your solution will likely help others who have a similar issue, and no one else seems to have any more ideas :) Thanks for your help.